# Why does the following code not initialize my JavaScript object?

Tags: javascript

```
MyClass = function() {
    var init = function() {
        console.log("Initializing");
    }
    this.init();
}
var myInstance = new MyClass();
```

When I run the above I get

TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'init'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because by declaring `init` as a `var`, or a local variable rather than a property of the object. As such, `init` does not become a member function of your object, which is why your code failed to run as you expected. Initialize it as `this.init = function() {` instead to achieve the expected behaviour.

http://jsfiddle.net/Y2Rvq/

Answer (score 4):

Local variables in the constructor's scope don't become properties of the instance.

Instead of `var init = function...;`, use `this.init = function...;`